# DBContext Inherit from multiple base class

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext

I have just implemented the DuendeIdentity Server and by DBContext looks like this.

```
public class DataContext : ApiAuthorizationDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DataContext(
        DbContextOptions options,
        IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions> operationalStoreOptions) : base(options, operationalStoreOptions)
    {
    }
 ...
```

I now wish to implement some basic Database Auditing which I have successfully done in the past using this https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/audit-trail-implementation-in-aspnet-core/ however it is implemented in this way

```
public abstract class AuditableIdentityContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public AuditableIdentityContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }
```

With the DataContext then inheriting from it like

```
public partial class DataContext : AuditContext
{
    public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
```

I am trying to understand how I may use the two together.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

C# doesn't have multiple inheritance.

Consider using your `ApiAuthorizationDbContext` separately from your application-specific DbContext. You can still use a `DbSet<ApplicationUser>` to reference your users from your application entities.

Comment: I'm not the backend guy, he's off sick so I don't really understand how to de-couple.  Would you have an example you could point to plz?